# having problems with fancy box options

Tags: jquery

im using fancy box 2.0.4 on my site which has a email contact triggered by a link and a pop up
email submission form that appears on page load. i am having a difficult time with the pop up that shows on page load. it seems that no matter what i do the options get ignored.i dont want the window to close if clicked outside of it in fact none of the options ive set are working.i have researched your site and google and havent had any luck.the pop up trigger is a div call out ('#inline')...here is a sample of that code..any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated seeing ive learned a great deal from your site. gratitude!

this is the code for the automated popup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fancybox.open( $('#inline'))({
    wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-effects',
    openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        openSpeed   : 2000,
        closeSpeed  : 1000,
    closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox

    helpers   : 
    { overlay : {closeClick: false}, // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
    speedIn: 2000, //<-- here you control the overlay speedIn
    speedOut: 1000,//<-- here you control the overlay speedOut

    }

   }).trigger("click")
});
```

Comment: sorry the code posted as a run on...ugh bad day!

Comment: There shouldnt have a comma after speedout option

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you show part of HTML code?

Comment: the form loads fine but when i click outside of it the window closes.the issue im having is the options i have set arent working to prevent this.something in the trigger event causing the pop up to go into default setting..and Karl you are correct about the comma i have been adding and taking options away must have missed the comma...thanks!